# jQuery autocomplete suggestions list doesn't change baclground color on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I use `jQuery autocomplete` to provide a list of suggestions even as the user types something into a text box. As the autocomplete method only provides a bland list, is use the `scss` file from [here](https://gist.github.com/daz/2168334) to style it the `bootstrap` way. If I am right, the following snippet from the file sets the background color on `hover` to the Twitter blue color:

```
&.ui-state-hover, &.ui-state-active {
      color: #ffffff;
      text-decoration: none;
      background-color: #0088cc;
      border-radius: 0px;
      -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
      -moz-border-radius: 0px;
      background-image: none;
    }
```

However, the background color remains white when i mouse-over the list items. How can I fix this?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pm8P7/)

Answer (score 2):

can u directly use `li.ui-menu-item:hover{background-color:#ccc}` to ur css see the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aashi/pm8P7/6/)
because in ur code the `<li>` is activating the class 'ui-state-hover' that is why it is not working

Comment: that works! any idea how I can change the font color too on hover?

Comment: same write that code like this li.ui-menu-item:hover{background-color:#ccc;color:#f00;}